# C# How to make a class accessible from all projects without circular reference

Tags: c#, oop

I want to create an exception class that should be accessible from all projects.
My project structure looks like this:

- Project: GUI (References to Project A/B)
- Project: A (References to Project B)
- Project: B (No referenc project)

No matter to which project I add the Exceptions class, I would always get a circular in at least one Project. I

I just want to be able to catch custom exceptions that are clearly defined for all projects within a solution.

Creating a new project only with the exception class would not look very nice.

How is something like this solved in OOP?

Comment: Please describe the project structure or find some other way of showing it - we really can't tell what you mean at the moment.

Comment: Tried to do it a little bit better. The table function did not work for some reason at least for me.

Comment: In case if you define an exception class inside the B assembly, how will it create a loop?

Comment: Exactly - in project B, it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

> Creating a new project only with the exception class would not look very nice.

This is exactly how you should approach it to avoid circular dependencies.
If you have functionality, nice and tidy isolated, it can be fit in a DLL with a very well defined purpose. You can reference this assembly in all projects without causing a circular reference.

So:

- create a new project
- add the required "shared" functionality
- Reference that project/dll in the other projects

You can later extend the project with similar shared functions and functionality.

---

As @DmytroOvdiienko points out:

> I believe together with the exception some code must be moved to new assembly.

This is a valid point. Most likely you'll find you can put more of your custom exception related functionality in there.

Comment: Exception class is an error data which is connected to some domain. E.g. you have some code and it throws an exception. I believe together with the exception some code must be moved to new assembly

Comment: Good point, I'll add your remark